# Модули в joomla3 и div

Tags: joomla, html

Есть сайт на joomla.
Верстаю отдельную страницу, и нужно что бы на этой странице были разные див="ид",для задания каждому из этих дивов фоновых картинок.

Проблема в том,что в одном из модулей (модуль главной страницы сайта) прописан 
div id="wrapper" и получается что этот див покрывает собой всё пространство, на каждой странице сайта.

Т.е. все что я верстаю,оказывается в этом диве,грубо говоря.
Когда создаю свои дивы с заданными айди на отдельной странице,они оказываются внутри div id="wrapper" и не могут растянуться на всю ширину.

Как сделать,что бы верстая отдельную страницу сайта я вышел за пределы этого дива и создал свой див с заданным мной айди?Как сделать что бы div id="wrapper" как бы закончился,как его закрыть на отдельной странице?

Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: То есть блоки внутри нужно сделать шире чем сам #wrapper ?

Comment: блоки должны быть растянуты на всю ширину,но они не растягиваются.
Плюс к этому,у меня должно на отдельной странице быть несколько блоков с разными фоновыми изображениями,а так как они оказываются все внутри wrapper,то фоновое изображение получается задать только для wparrep, а для других блоков не получается задать фон

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется тут два варианта:

1. Расширить `#wrapper` до 100% и уже от этого отталкиваться, редактируя внутренние блоки.
2. Вынести позицию модуля за пределы `#wrapper`. Но это не совсем удобно будет.

Comment: wrapper итак растянут на всю ширину.
Проблема как я сказал ,в задании фоновых изображений для разных блоков. Фон для блока можно задать только один,и получается для первого блока я задаю фон,а для следующего уже не выходит. Т.е. для следующего блока я создаю отдельный 
div id="primer" задаю ему фон,но он уже идет не на всю ширину,т.к. находится внутри wrapper.

Про второй способ не понял,сможете подробнее объяснить?

Comment: Если блок wrapper во всю ширину, то почему нельзя задать внутреннему блоку 100% ширину? Или я не полностью понял вашу ситуацию. А есть ли "живой пример" чтобы посмотреть? Так было бы удобней и быстрей.

Comment: Пытался задать полную ширину внутреннему блоку,но ничего не выходит,может я что-то не правильно сделал. Как бы вы реализовали задание фулл вид для внутреннего блока?

Пример будет проблемно показать,к сожалению.

Comment: Возможно, вот так: https://jsfiddle.net/mky14yw1/2/

Comment: Буду пробовать,благодарю.